# preprending and appending to a cstring

Tags: c++

I  have the following string tok_str which is like "default.png" I would like to preprend char ' and append char ' too.

That's what I have done, but the chars are appended and prepended in the wrong places

```
char *tok_str = const_cast<char*>(mReader->getAttributeValue(pAttrIdx));

      char * mod_tok = new char[tok_str_len+2];

      mod_tok[0] = '\'';

      size_t len = strlen(tok_str);
      size_t i;

      memmove(mod_tok + len, mod_tok, strlen(mod_tok) + 1);

      for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      {
          mod_tok[i] = tok_str[i];
      }


      char *dup;
      char *cstr="'";

      sprintf(mod_tok,"%s%s",cstr,(dup=strdup(mod_tok)));
      free(dup);
```

Comment: That's not C code, that's C++ code. And for that you should really use `std::string` and things will suddenly become *much* easier.

Comment: Use std::string!

Comment: As has been mentioned use 'std::string' and then, if you really need to convert back to a c string, use the associated method for C++ strings 'c_str()'

Comment: `char *cstr="'"` is ill-formed in C++ (since C++11) because in C++ string literals are const and your pointer is non-const.

Comment: @Spektre should the code that has the function l2g and g2l be there ? can you post these functions ?

Comment: @Spektre this is the stl cube https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:253861

Comment: I incresed the z of the vertices, and I get the following triangles, they are above the mesh, and the prims is not drawn, i alsed added the code for the joints, https://imgur.com/a/V3F4u

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yp8Jy

Comment: @Spektre Why the supporter doesn't generate correctly as in the image,there is just on triangle is generated

Comment: @Spektre I found that the models that I use the cube and the space invader is not centered at the origin, what's the solution for that?

Comment: maybe that's the problem ?

Comment: @Spektre Can you tell me how would I add p2 point ? because center is p0+p1, how would p2 would affect the center ?  There are no supporters added at all, just a small triangle

Comment: @andreahmed that leave as is but in the loop where you compute min,max (p0,p1) you are computing only form `triangle.p0,triangle.p1` and not using `triangle.p2` at all

Comment: @Spektre I have fixed the center calculations, as you see there are a lot of supporters generated, I tried to play with the parameters but still not working correctly https://imgur.com/a/mNDaH

Comment: @Spektre please try to review this if you have some time https://pastebin.com/GPXU4n3i

Comment: @Spektre please help :(

Comment: @Spektre The code doesn't work with a sample file like that
http://forums.reprap.org/file.php?88,file=353,filename=Star.stl,download=1

Comment: @andreahmed of coarse it does work see: [your star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWBep.png). You still did not set `grid0,1,ha` properly if `grid0` is bigger than your object projected half size onto `xy` plane (`size[0],size[1]`) then you do not place any supporters as you miss the object with that grid. And you should find that out while debugging immediately. You can force to use center position in such case ... but no I will not code that. As I mentioned the code need to handle a lot of edge cases to make it usable in real app and that would not fit into SO answer limit in any way.

Comment: @andreahmed try `grid0=rmin*0.5; grid1=grid0*0.4; ha=grid0*0.2;` where `rmin=min(size[0],size[1])` but that is not correct from the technology point of view as grid sizes should reflect used material, weight, height and technology used.

Comment: @Spektre It works perfectly with the start, but with other shapes, the above equation, doesn't usualy work.. give me the algorithms and I will write it, so that it is a production code.

Comment: @andreahmed there are none  those are just distances ... (inverse of densities) and should be set by target printing technology. So if any equations are you should look for them in the underlying printing technology and material engineering ... As I mentioned before I can not help you there as that is far from  mine expertise and requires full background knowledge on the stuff you are dealing with

Comment: @Spektre Thanks so much, I tried that sample file, it doesn't work. http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/stla/bottle.stl

Comment: @Spektre What are the edge cases that you mentioned ? I need to solve them, just tell me the algorithms in the answer to the question

Comment: @Spektre Please help :). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue using null-terminated byte strings there are a few things you need to think of and do.

The first is of course the ***null-terminated*** part. A string of X characters needs space for X+1 to include the terminator.

The second is that all you need is really a single `sprintf` (or better yet `snprintf`) call (once you allocated memory):

```
char* mod_tok = new char[strlen(tok_str) + 3];  // +2 for the extra characters, +1 for terminator
snprintf(mod_tok, strlen(tok_str) + 3, "'%s'", tok_str);
```

That is it, now you have added the single quotes in front and at the end of the original string.

Comment: May want to reuse the result of `strlen(tok_str)`, or will the optimizer be able to prove that it won't change?

Comment: That solution doesn't apply the uppercase modifier to the string.

Comment: when I apply strstr(mod_tok, "\"") to find the the char ", it gives me null

Comment: @StefanoBuora What upper-case modifier? The OP doesn't do any upper-casing?

Comment: @andreahmed That's because you try to find the *double* quote, not the single quote you seemingly want to add.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, my bad, misread "strdup" in the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to improve:

- usage of const when possible
- len vs tok_str_len, use only one.
- the memmove done in the middle seems to have no effect on the final result
- pay attention to the indexes in the for loop
- be aware that strlen doesn't count the NULL terminator
- if your code starts to mix new/delete with free try to refactor it

That's my proposal:

```
//keep it const and protect your data
const char *tok_str = mReader->getAttributeValue(pAttrIdx);
//retrive the len once for all (const, no one is supposed to change it)
const size_t len = strlen(tok_str);
char * mod_tok = new char[len+3]; // 2 "'" + '\0'

mod_tok[0] = '\'';
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    mod_tok[i+1] =tok_str[i];
}
mod_tok[len+1] = '\'';
mod_tok[len+2] = '\0';

//done.

//later...
delete[] mod_tok;
```

Enjoy your coding!
Stefano
PS: I agree, though, that a use of std::string is reccomended.

Comment: when I apply strstr(mod_tok, "\"") to find the the char ", it gives me null

Comment: do you mean strstr(mod_tok, "\'") instead? " and ' are not the same thing